# Custom features in beeswarm plot of shap

Tags: python, plot, shap, beeswarm

I have a causal inference model with

```
featurizer=PolynomialFeatures(degree=3)
```

which includes a degree 3 polynomial in X variable. I get the plot for interpretability too with:

```
shap.plots.beeswarm(shap_values['Y0']['T0'])
```

but the plot shows me the shap values for `X0`, `X0^2` and `X0^3` as:

[image]

However, is it possible that the beeswarm plot show me only the values for X0?

Best regards

Comment: Please [reprex]

Answer (score 0):

X0 and X0^3 are the column 0 and 2 of the array named main_effects inside the object T0, the subplot with these features could be:

```
ind = [0, 2]

raw_shap_values = np.take(shap_values['Y0']['T0'].main_effects, ind, axis=1)
raw_data_values = np.take(shap_values['Y0']['T0'].data, ind, axis=1)
shap.summary_plot(raw_shap_values, features=raw_data_values, plot_type="violin")
```